# Xml auto suggestion does not work for new android design support library widgets

Tags: android, android-xml, android-design-library

I have updated my android SDK to [latest design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). I have tried to add new widgets in xml. But xml auto suggestion didn't work.

I have added the dependency in app/build.gradle as they mentioned.

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

What else I have to do?